# Making WYSIWYG, cant apply style to selected (highlighted) text in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

this is my first time as "writer", i always read all the useful people posts but i had never write one before. I decided to write because i couldn´t find the answer to this specific issue.
I am trying to do a wysiwyg with jQuery and JavaScript and the problem that i have is that i cant apply style to a specific div that had some text inside of it selected.
I am doing the following:

```
$("#idofthediv").mouseup(function () {
    var selObj = window.getSelection();
    alert("Selected: " + selObj);
    selObj.style.color = 'red';
});
```

I got the selected text in the alert but i can´t apply the style to that text or even to the div that contains that text. (the third line selObj.style.color = 'red'; is not working is somthing i tried but knowing it is wrong)

Any idea?

Thanks a lot

Tomas

Answer (score 0):

You can try out something like this:

```
var spn = '<span class="red">' + selObj.toString() + '</span>';
var newContent = document.activeElement.innerHTML.replace(selObj, spn.toString());
document.activeElement.innerHTML = newContent;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/49BeS/1/

Wrap your selected text inside a span element, which you style appropriately, then get the active element and make a replace.
The problem is, that the replace function will replace the first occurence of the string and not the selected one. You could however modify it to replace all occurances of the selected string. I just don't know if there is a way to replace exactly the selected occurance.